# Telerik client event - find out who is the sender

Tags: telerik, client-side, checkboxlist, radlistbox

I have a javascript function that is called on "OnClientSelectedIndexChanged" event from a RadListBox element. 
The same function can be fired on the "OnClientItemChecked" event in case the RadListBox has the property `checkBox == true`.
How can I find if the function was called on item check or selection changed? I need to get the value of the element like this:

```
function getVal(sender, args) {
    var Item = args.get_item();
    var ItemType = [...] // here shold be the senders type
    if(ItemType == CHECKBOX){
        if(Item.get_checked()) return Item.get_value();
        else return null;
    } else {
        return Item.get_value();
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function getVal(sender, args) 
{
    var Item = args.get_item();

    if (args.get_domEvent().target.className == "rlbCheck")
    {
        //this is checkbox
        if (Item.get_checked()) return Item.get_value();
        else return null;
    } else {
        return Item.get_value();
    }
}
```

Comment: If the element who fires this function is a textbox, the args parameter is an empty object. How can I find out, in this case, if the sender is a textbox? Keep in mind that this function is called by almost all the telerik elements in case of focusout. Thanks!